# To add a attachment icon

Tags: android, android-edittext, attachment, android-drawable

I need to add an attachment icon in the right bottom of a EditText as shown in the image. Can anyone help how I can achieve this???

[image: I would like to add an attachment in the right bottom of this EditText]

Answer (score 0):

The general hierarchy pattern for this request is :

```
<FrameLayout android:width="match_parent" 
             android:height="match_parent">

    <EditText android:width="match_parent" 
              android:height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView android:width="wrap_content" 
               android:height="wrap_content" 
               android:margin="5dp" 
               android:src="@drawable/ic_attach"
               android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a relative layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="5" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/attach"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think directly its not possible in edittext but you can do some trick for this.
please see below code, it might help you.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:minLines="10" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```